# How to trigger "ref.current.open()" from parent component in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I currently working in a React Native project using 'https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-raw-bottom-sheet' lib to handle bottom up panel.

I want to trigger bottom up panel everytime I click a button in parent component instead of clicking a button in child component, how do I can achieve this.

Bottom Up Panel child component:

```
const refRBSheet : any = useRef();
 View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={{width:200}}>
              <Button title="OPEN BOTTOM SHEET" onPress={() => refRBSheet.current.open()} />
            </View>
      <RBSheet
        ref={refRBSheet}
        closeOnDragDown={true}
        closeOnPressMask={true}
        animationType='slide'
        customStyles={{
          wrapper: {
            backgroundColor: "transparent"
          },
          draggableIcon: {
            backgroundColor: "#999999"
          },
          container:{
            backgroundColor:'#101010',
            height:450,
          }
        }}
      >
        <MyComponent/>
      </RBSheet>
  </View>
```

My parent component:

```
<View>
 <Button title="I want to click this button and trigger ButtomUpPanel/>
 <BottomUpPanel/>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `useImperativeHandle` hook in your parent

```
const refRBSheet : any = useRef();

const open = () => {
  refRBSheet.current.open()
};

useImperativeHandle(refRBSheet, () => ({
  open,
}));
```

Then pass the `ref` down to your components.

```
<View>
 <Button onPress={()=>open()} title="I want to click this button and trigger ButtomUpPanel/>
 <BottomUpPanel ref={refRBSheet} />
</View>
```

Remember `useImperativeHandle` should be used with `forwardRef`.

Comment: THanks for your help but It is not working with following warning:
"Function component cannot be given refs. Did you mean to use React.fowardRefs

Comment: You need to wrap your `BottomUpPanel` in `React.forwardRef`. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref

Answer (score 0):

Actually after hours of researching I finally found a way for my own question:

To pass a ref to child component from parent component I use

> forwardRef

By importing import

```
{forwardRef} from 'react';
```

Then in my case i just wrap my child component in forwardRef:

```
const DetailPanelBottomUp: FC<IDetailPanel> = forwardRef(
  ({imgUrl, title, contentUrl,value}, ref: any) => {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <RBSheet
          ref={ref}
          onClose={() => setSocialNet(false)}
          closeOnDragDown={true}
          closeOnPressMask={true}
          animationType="slide"
          customStyles={{
            wrapper: {
              backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            },
            draggableIcon: {
              backgroundColor: '#999999',
            },
            container: {
              backgroundColor: '#101010',
              height: 450,
            },
          }}>
        <MyComponent/>
      </RBSheet>
  </View>
```

And in my parent component I just declare

> useRef

and its action then pass the ref to child component as a props

```
 const refRBSheet : any = useRef();

  const open = () => {
    refRBSheet.current.open();
  };

<View>
 <DetailPanelBottomUp title={actionItem.title} contentUrl={actionItem.src} ref= 
 {refRBSheet} imgUrl={actionItem.src} />
 <Button onPress={()=>open()} title="I want to click this button and trigger ButtomUpPanel/>
</View>
```